# EF Update Formviews in a Transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, transactions

I want to update two formviews within a transaction. if one of them fails the other should fail too. Formviews have their own entity datasources.

```
button1_click(..........)
{
   formview1.updateItem(true);
   formview2.updateItem(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so this may not be the simplest thing in the world.

The basic answer is that yes you can do it.  And the code would be similar to this if the updateItem method opens the db connection.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    formview1.updateItem(true);
    formview2.updateItem(true);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

If on the other hand the connections are already open by the time updateItem is called then you will need to do something more like

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    formview1.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transcation.Current);
    formview2.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transcation.Current);
    formview1.updateItem(true);
    formview2.updateItem(true);
    scope.Complete();
}
```